# Elastalert2 rules folder config not working

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, arguments, elastalert, elastalert2

I'm using Elastalert2 now to get notifications from error log in slack.

We need to receive alarms of all service logs through our dozens of rules.

Docker builds ElastAlert2 and deploy it on Argocd.

But, there is a problem that the rules_folder config does not work

There is rules_folder in config.yaml

```
 rules_folder: /home/elastalert/rules
```

and this is Example Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.13-slim

# installation
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip \
  && pip3 install cryptography elastalert2

ENV LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

# add configuration and alarm
RUN mkdir -p /home/elastalert
WORKDIR /home/elastalert

ADD ./config.yaml /home/elastalert
COPY ./rules /home/elastalert/rules
```

and this is run command

```
    command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]
        args:
          - >-
            echo "Finda Elastalert is started!!" &&
            elastalert-create-index &&
            elastalert --verbose --config config.yaml
            
            ...
```

but error occur like...
[error][1]

I think the rule files cannot be imported as args.
In other words, it seems that rules_folder does not apply

If, specify a specific rule file in the start command, it works well.
For example,

```
 elastalert --verbose --config config.yaml --rule ./rules/example/example.yaml
```

However, it can only execute one rule.

We have dozens of rules.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solve.

Don't store empty yaml in your rules/ sub.

The problem was that I commented out all the yaml files except the test rule yaml for the operation test.

By replacing the commented yaml file with another extension such as .text.

Now elastalert recognizes and operates all rules.